# Weird indexed inner product notation

Tags: inner-products

I am working on a paper that has the following formula that is written as
$$
\sum^{-1}_{j=-\mu} <r_{j+\mu},s_j>
$$

Here, I am interpreting $r$ and $s$ as vectors. $\mu$ is a scalar number. What is the meaning of the vector indices? Also, I do not think that vector $r_0$ and $r_1$ are distinct vectors. Could they be a shifted version of each other?

This is from the following paper:
Mehlan, Ralf, and Heinrich Meyr. "Optimum frame synchronization for asynchronous packet transmission." Proceedings of ICC'93-IEEE International Conference on Communications. Vol. 2. IEEE, 1993.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense, so I went to the paper and couldn't find the formula as you have written. What I did find was $$\sum_{j=-\mu}^{-1}<r_{j+\mu},p_{P+j}>$$
All other parts in the paper where it contains $<r_{j+\mu},s_{j}>$ the summation starts at $0$ which is good because then $s$ does not have a negative index. $r_0$ and $r_1$ are distinct as they are defined in equation (1) and it is further evident in Figure (1).

For the summation above we have positive indices since when $j=-\mu$ you have $<r_{-\mu+\mu},p_{P-\mu}>=<r_{0},p_{P-\mu}>$ and all the following terms for $j=-\mu+1,-\mu+2,\ldots,-1$ both $r$ and $p$ have positive indices. Specifically $r_{1},r_{2},\ldots,r_{\mu-1}$ and $p_{P-\mu+1},p_{P-\mu+2},\ldots,p_{P-1}$.

If I indeed did miss the formula indicate what page.

Comment: I'm sorry that I input an incomplete version of the equation. You have found the piece where I was struggling to understand. 

I can see that if $r_0$ is in the inner product notation, it must be a vector. So what is the number of elements of $r_0$?

For example, consider a constant scalar number indexed like $k_1, k_2, k_3, ...$. Then, what I see is that 

$r_0 = (k_1, k_2, k_3, ...)$
$r_1 = (k_2, k_3, k_4, ...)$

I hope it does make sense.

Comment: I just had a helpful insight that could solve this.

Since I am working with scalar samples in $\mathbf{r}$, then can I just change inner product to simple multiplication?

Comment: @Odds'n'Ends if each $r_i$ is a scalar then your observation is correct - I leave this to you to confirm. But if they are vectors then you will need to use the inner product

Comment: ok. It makes sense now. Thanks for helping me.